# Get Response object from asp.net Button Onclick Event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I have an ASP.NET Webform, Which includes a server side Button. I have registered an Onclick button event on it.

```
<asp:Button ID="UploadButton" CssClass="btn add btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Upload File" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />
```

what i am trying to do is,

On the Server Side, after Processing the required things, i have filled a response object, which i want to return to client Side (like assign it to a javascript variable).

**How can i get the object returned from button click event on client side.**

```
protected ResponseModel UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel(); 
  //Processing File
  //filling Response Object
  return responseModel 
}
```

Initially return type of the `UploadButton_Click()` method was void.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how complex or simple is your response object but have you tried using a `<asp:HiddenField />`? Something like:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField" runat="server" value="" />
```

Then in your code-behind:

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Processing File
  //filling Response Object
  hiddenField.Value = responseObject.customProperty;
}
```

Javascript should be able to find it via:

```
document.getElementById('<%=hiddenField.ClientID%>')
```